# i got a stuck pc and i got bsod ,i think it is due to without earth wire

Tags: power-supply

I am using my pc without earth wire if i touch the panel of my pc i get shocked ,i think this cause over heating of pc ,my pc stuck often and i get bsod problem ,is using pc without earth wire cause pc dead

Comment: A Blue Screen of Death is a software thing, which **might** be due to some hardware issue. **If** it is due to a hardware issue, it's hard to imagine it directly being result of insufficient earthing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The fact that you get shocked from touching the PC strongly suggests that the failure to have the PC properly grounded was half the cause of your PC dying. The other half of the problem is there is an electric fault somewhere. It could be inside your PC, or it could be in another appliance, wire or circuit, and the fault is conducted to your PC.

Comment: Or perhaps the power supply has line to ground Y capacitors, like nearly all such power supplies do, which allow leaking a tiny amount of current to the chassis which can be felt if it's not grounded properly.